# Sticky navigation bar extending to the right side past margin

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I have a webpage that uses a navigation bar using the following code:

```
body {
  margin: 3em;
}
#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```
<div id="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
</div>
```

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

The navbar div extends past the right side of the body even though the body has a margin of 3em. How can I prevent the div from expanding?

I tried adding `width: 100%;` and `box-sizing: border-box;` to `#navbar` css but they make no difference. I cannot think of any more solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the margin does affect the fixed navbar, it is still defining its width as 100% of the html, not 100% of the body.

There's a few ways to fix this. One way is to use the `calc()` function to subtract the margin(or padding) of the body from the width of the navbar.

Here's a jsfiddle adapting your navbar to use that solution: [jsfiddle](https://codepen.io/samhsabin/pen/NWJdBaB)

I subtract the margin(from both sides, so 6em in your example) from the width of the navbar.

Here is a very similar question(same but they're using padding instead of margin) that may bring more insights: [Position fixed with width 100% is ignoring body padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159588/position-fixed-with-width-100-is-ignoring-body-padding#:%7E:text=A%20fixed%20element%20is%20not,use%20a%20padding%20on%20that.)

And here is an article with a similar solution: [CSS padding-right disappear when position fixed width 100%](https://www.paddingleft.com/2018/07/24/CSS-position-fixed-full-width/)